# Is $\tau:=\inf\left\{t\ge0:\int_0^tc(X_s)\:{\rm d}s\ge\xi\right\}$ a stopping time?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stopping-times

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ be a measurable space;
- $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a filtration on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$;
- $(E,\mathcal E)$ be a measurable space;
- $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ be an $(E,\mathcal E)$-valued process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$;
- $c:E\to[0,\infty)$ be $\mathcal E$-measurable;
- $\xi$ be a real-valued random variable on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$.

> How can we shot that $$\tau:=\inf\left\{t\ge0:\int_0^tc(X_s)\:{\rm d}s\ge\xi\right\}$$ is an $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge0}$-stopping time (imposing suitable additional assumptions, if necessary)?

I guess we need to assume that $F:=c\circ X$ is (pathwisely) locally Lebesgue integrable so that we can infer that $$G_t:=\int_0^tF_s\:{\rm d}s\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge0$$ is continuous. From this continuity, we can infer that $$\tau\le t\Leftrightarrow G_t\ge\xi\tag1$$ for all $t\ge0$.

Next, I guess we need to assume that $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ is $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge0}$-progressive, since this ensures that $(G_t)_{t\ge0}$ is $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge0}$-adapted.

Now it seems like we need to assume that $\xi$ is $\mathcal F_0$-measurable in order to conclude from $(1)$ (using the fact that if $Y,Z$ are real-valued random variables on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$, then $\{Y\le Z\}\in\sigma(Y,Z)$).

**EDIT**: In practice, I would like to take $$F_t:=\sigma(X_s,s\le t)\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge0$$ and $\xi$ being independent of $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ and exponentially distributed. If we really need to assume that $\xi$ is measurable with respect to $\mathcal F_0=\sigma(X_0)$, how do we need to argue that the $((X_t)_{t\ge0},\xi)$ exist on a common probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$?

Comment: It's not true that $\tau\leq t\iff G_t\geq \xi$. The only direction which is true is $G_t\geq \xii\implies \tau\leq t$...

Comment: @Surb  Let $M$ be a topological space, $g:[0,\infty)\to M$ be right-continuous, $B\subseteq M$ be closed and $$\sigma:=\inf\underbrace{\{t\ge0:g(t)\in B\}}_{=:\:I}.$$ Then it holds $$\sigma\le t\Leftrightarrow\exists s\in I:s\le t\tag2$$ for all $t\ge0$. Apply this, for fixed $\omega\in\Omega$, with $g(t):=G_t(\omega)$ for $t\ge0$ and $B:=[\xi(\omega),\infty)$; hence $M=\mathbb R$ and $\sigma=\tau(\omega)$. Noting that this paricular $g$ is nondecreasing $(2)$ can be replaced by $$\sigma\le t\Leftrightarrow t\in I\tag3$$ for all $t\ge0$. If I'm missing something, please let me know.

Comment: If $g$ non decreasing you right, I didn't see that $c\geq 0$ in your OP... So, indeed, you right :-)

Comment: @Surb Yeah, I guessed that you've missed that assumption. Do you think we need to assume $\mathcal F_0$-measurability of $\xi$? In practice, I would like to take $\mathcal F_t=\sigma(X_s,s\le t)$ and $\xi$ being independent of $X$ and exponentially distributed and I'm unsure how I would need to argue that such a random variable must exist which is also $\mathcal F_0$-measurable ...

Comment: I think you will need to assume your filtration is "right-continuous" $\mathcal F_{t+} = \mathcal F_t$, where $$\mathcal F_{t+} = \bigcap_{s>t}\mathcal F_s$$

Comment: If you assume that $\xi$ is $\mathcal{F}_0$-measurable then the process $Y_t:=-\xi+\int_0^t c(X_s)\,\mathrm{d}s$ is continuous and adapted. Then $\tau$ is a [hitting time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitting_time) (the first time $Y$ hits the set $\{0\}$).

Comment: @GEdgar Could you please clarify for which of my claims you think I need right-continuity of the filtration? If we assume that $\xi$ is $\mathcal F_0$-measurable, and $X$ is $\mathcal F$-progressive, it immediately follows $\{\tau\le t\}=\{G_t\ge\xi\}\in\mathcal F_t$ for all $t\ge0$. Or do you mean that we don't need to assume that $\xi$ is $\mathcal F_0$-measurable, when we assume right-continuity of the filtration instead?

Comment: @jakobdt Yes, $(1)$ is a special case of the fact that the hitting time of a closed set for a right-continuous process is a stopping time. But as I wrote in my edit, I'm not sure how strong the assumption that $\xi$ is $\mathcal F_0$-measurable really is.

Comment: It will depend on what you need from the filtration. You could define $\mathcal{F}_t=\sigma(\xi,(X_s)_{0\leq s\leq t})$. Then $\xi$ is $\mathcal{F}_0$-measurable, and $(X_t)_{t\geq0}$ is $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\geq0}$-adapted.